# Display array items that have title in jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I have this code:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
    {% for page in site.pages %}
      {% if page.title %}
        <li><a href="{{ page.url | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I don't have any pages with title yet but I may have in the future and tidy-html5, that I'm using to output html with indent, give warning that ul is empty. Without title check it output generated pages tags or global pages like sitemap or rss feed.

Is there a way to first filter array and then don't show nav if the array is empty, something like:

```
{% pages = [for page in pages if page.title] %}

{% if pages.length %}
  <nav>
    <ul>
    ....
    </ul>
  </nav>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only pages with titles:

```
pages = site.pages.select{ |p| p.title }
```

So your code might look something like:

```
{% assign pages = site.pages.select{ |p| p.title } %}

{% if pages %}
  <ul>
    {% for page in pages %}
      <li>...</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: got error `Liquid syntax error (line 4): Unknown tag 'pages'`

Comment: In my OP I forgot to close out the first code block with a `%}`. Edited with update.

Comment: I've notice your error, your solution work but you need to add `{% assign pages = .... %}` as in [liquid docs](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/variable/)